# Connecting digital piano via earphone

Tags: digital-piano

I have purchased a Vault Caeser MK2 digital piano. When I connect its output to earphones via a 6.5 to 3.5 mm jack, I’m still hearing the audio through the piano speakers instead of through the earphones.

How can I solve this issue? Is the problem related to the piano or the connectors?

Comment: What do the instructions tell? On a piano of that value, I'd have thought there would be a way to either keep the speakers sounding, or defeat them when the cans socket is used. Probably hidden in a menu, somewhere.

Comment: If you are hearing the speakers and not the headphones it is possible the jack is not fully engaged. The headphone jack disables the speakers on most pianos.

Comment: It shouldn’t be too hard to test the earphones and jack on another device to see if they are working correctly.